# C++ - OOP design - multiple inheritance and pure virtual method

Tags: c++, oop

I have this problem, that I dont know, how to solve correctly.

```
class A : public B, public C
{
   virtual void GetSomethingElse()
   {
   }
}

class B
{
   public void GetSomething()
   {      
      GetSomethingElse();
   }

   virtual void GetSomethingElse() = 0;
}

class C
{
   virtual void GetSomethingElse() = 0;
}
```

Basically, what I have are two abstract classes `B`, `C`. Usually, I just need to inherit one of them, but in some particular cases, I need both of them.

How to correctly solve this problem with `GetSomethingElse()` method, that needs to be called from `B`. If I inherit only `B`, it will be implementted in child. If only from `C`, all is still OK. 
However, if I inherit `B` and `C`, I have some "weird" design, that resemlbes diamond inheritance problem, but it is quite not the same.

Comment: I do not see an issue inheriting from B and C. What problem are you having, exactly?

Comment: Can you provide code that actually generates the error you wish to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mentioned it is quite different from diamond problem.

Your design is correct and not weired. Having GetSomeThingElse as pure virtual is to enforce the child to define it. Defining it if it is because of C or B is not a design issue. 
You would have a design issue if it were pure virtual in one and virtual in the other (B or C) as one gives you the choice and the other by obligation.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A : public B, public C
{
   virtual void GetSomethingElse()
   {
   }
}

class B:public class D
{
   public void GetSomething()
   {      
      GetSomethingElse();
   }

   virtual void GetSomethingElse()
   {
   }
}

class C:public class D
{
   virtual void GetSomethingElse()
   {
   }
}

//here's the only pure virtual base class
 class D
{
   virtual void GetSomethingElse() = 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As they are abstract, you need to overwrite the method in `class A`.
Each object will know if it is a `B` or a `C`, so it will call the right function.

if, however, your class C has no function `GetSomething()`, then your inheritance structure is the wrong way around - remember the logic of inheritance is that every object of a derived class is an object of the parent class too? So if an A is not a B because is doesn't have such a call, something is wrong.

Another point is to derive `virtual`, so the two identical functions are considered the same: `class A : virtual public B, virtual public C`

Did you consider making a class that is the parent of B and C? If they don't have a common parent, why do they have a function each with the same name?